# Using a different vertex and fragment shader for each object in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader

I have a scene with multiple objects in webgl. For each object I want to use a different vertex and a fragment shader. My first question is, is it possible to have a shader for each object? I am aware it is possible in opengl.

This is something similar pseudo code of what I had in mind. Any example would be much appreciated.

```
glenableshader
draw triangle
gldisableshader

glenableshader
draw square
gldisableshader
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to? As far as I know it can be fairly expensive to use different shaders, especially because you remove any capability of sprite batching, and combining draw calls. What you would have to do is use the code to create a shader program, and pass a string of shader code for each object. Keep a reference of the shader program with each object i suppose.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Start with: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up pretty much any WebGL example and turn it into a multiple shader example.

Pseudo code

```
// At init time
for each shader program
    create and compile vertex shader
    create and compile fragment shader
    create program and attach shaders
    link program
    record locations of attributes and uniforms

for each model/set of geometry/points/data 
    create buffer(s) for model
    copy data into buffer(s) for model

for each texture
    create texture
    usually asynchronously load textures

// at draw time
clear

for each model
   useProgram(program for model)
   setup attributes for model
   setup textures for model
   set uniforms for model
   draw
```

This is no different than drawing 1 model with 1 shader program. Just do the same setup.

a little more code...

For setting up attributes would look something like

```
for each attribute used by model
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attribLocation);
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferWithDataForAttribute);
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(attribLocation, ...);
```

Setting up textures (might) look something liek this

```
for each texture used by model
   gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + ndx);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

Finally you'd use the program

```
gl.useProgram(programForModel);
for each uniform
   gl.uniform???(uniformLocation, uniformValue);

gl.drawArrays(...) 
or 
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferOfIndicesForModel);
gl.drawElements(...);
```