# WebGl adding multiple objects to one canvas

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

This is my first experiment in WebGL: I am trying to add a cube, octahedron and tetrahedron to a single canvas. I programmed each shape separately and tested them: they each work when living inside their own canvases. When I tried adding them together, that's when things go wrong. At present I only see the octahedron spinning about (no, it is not obscuring the other shapes, I have checked). When I comment the octahedron out, I see the cube and tetrahedron spinning around, but their colour buffers have been mixed up and are not what I wanted (when I try to separate their colour buffers, nothing renders to the screen). I realise there are inconsistencies in how I coded these, but the present configuration was the only way I could get both those two objects to show. Now the recent addition of the octahedron made the previous two disappear.

I sense the issue relates to vertex and colour buffers, but I don’t have enough experience and background to know what to amend. Do I instantiate a colour buffer for each of these? That would make sense. I tried and this but it did not go well for the first two shapes, hence the mixing of colour buffers.

Would be much appreciated if anyone could advise / help me out on this. Have been spending countless hours trying to get to grips with this problem.

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var NumVertices  = 36;

var points = [];
var colors = [];

var pointsT = [];
var colorsT = [];

var pointsO = [];
var colorsO = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis = 0;
var theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

var thetaLoc;

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL is not available" ); }


    // --------------- Cube --------------------------

    colorCube();

    // --------------- Tetrahedron -------------------

    colorTetra();

    // --------------- Octohedron --------------------

    colorOcto();


    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);


    // --------------- Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    // --------------- Cube --------------------------
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta"); 


    // --------------- Tetrahedron -------------------

    var tcBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tcBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var tvColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( tvColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( tvColor );

    var tvBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tvBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var tvPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( tvPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( tvPosition );


    // --------------- Octohedron --------------------      

    var ocBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ocBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsO), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var ovColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( ovColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( ovColor );

    var ovBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ovBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsO), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var ovPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( ovPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( ovPosition );

    render();
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    // Render cube
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    // Render tetrahedron
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length );

    // Render sphere
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, pointsO.length );
    requestAnimFrame( render );
}


// DEFINE CUBE

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

function quad(a, b, c, d) 
{
    var vertices = [
        vec3( -0.25, -0.25,  0.25 ),
        vec3( -0.25,  0.25,  0.25 ),
        vec3(  0.25,  0.25,  0.25 ),
        vec3(  0.25, -0.25,  0.25 ),
        vec3( -0.25, -0.25, -0.25 ),
        vec3( -0.25,  0.25, -0.25 ),
        vec3(  0.25,  0.25, -0.25 ),
        vec3(  0.25, -0.25, -0.25 )
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        [ 0.9, 0.9, 0.2, 1.0 ],  // oarnge
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // green
        [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // blue
        [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // magenta
        [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],  // white
        [ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ]   // cyan
    ];

    // Partion the quad into two triangles in order for
    // WebGL to be able to render it.      
    // vertex color assigned by the index of the vertex

    var indices = [ a, b, c, a, c, d ];

    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        points.push( vertices[indices[i]] );
        colors.push( vertexColors[indices[i]] );

        //for solid colored faces use 
        //colors.push(vertexColors[a]);    
    }
}

// DEFINE TETRAHEDRON

function colorTetra(){

    var verticesT = [
        vec3(  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.3500 ),
        vec3(  0.0000,  0.3500,  0.1500 ),
        vec3( -0.3500, -0.1500,  0.1500 ),
        vec3(  0.3500, -0.1500,  0.1500 )
    ];

    tetra(verticesT[0], verticesT[1], verticesT[2], verticesT[3]);
}

function makeTetra( a, b, c, color )
{
    // add colors and vertices for one triangle

    var baseColors = [
        vec3(0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0),
        vec3(0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0),
        vec3(0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 1.0),
        vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0)
    ];

    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( a );
    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( b );
    colors.push( baseColors[color] );
    points.push( c );
}

function tetra( p, q, r, s )
{
    // tetrahedron with each side using
    // a different color

    makeTetra( p, r, q, 0 );
    makeTetra( p, r, s, 1 );
    makeTetra( p, q, s, 2 );
    makeTetra( q, r, s, 3 );
}


// DEFINE OCTOHEDRON

function colorOcto(){

    var verticesO = [
        vec3(  0.4000, 0.0000, 0.0000 ),        
        vec3(  0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000 ),
        vec3(  0.0000, 0.4000, 0.0000 ),
        vec3(  0.4000, 0.4000, 0.0000 ),
        vec3(  0.2000, 0.2000, 0.3000 ),
        vec3(  0.2000, 0.2000, -0.3000 )
    ];

    octo(verticesO[0], verticesO[1], verticesO[2], verticesO[3], verticesO[4], verticesO[5]);   
}

function makeOcto( a, b, c, color )
{
    // add colors and vertices for one triangle

    var baseColors = [
        vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0),
        vec3(0.3, 0.4, 0.9, 1.0),
        vec3(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0),
    ];

    colorsO.push( baseColors[color] );
    pointsO.push( a );
    colorsO.push( baseColors[color] );
    pointsO.push( b );
    colorsO.push( baseColors[color] );
    pointsO.push( c );
}

function octo( a, b, c, d , e, f)
{
    // tetrahedron with each side using
    // a different color

    makeOcto( a, d, e, 0 );
    makeOcto( a, b, e, 1 );
    makeOcto( b, c, e, 0 );
    makeOcto( c, d, e, 1 );
    makeOcto( a, d, f, 1 );
    makeOcto( a, b, f, 2 );
    makeOcto( b, c, f, 1 );
    makeOcto( c, d, f, 2 );
}
```

I uploaded the complete code structure here:

https://gist.github.com/Carla-de-Beer/10ad7c7309fad48d94df

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to setup the program, then attributes and uniforms for each model before you draw it.

```
use program for cube
set attributes for cube
set uniforms for cube
draw cube

use program for tetrahedon
set attributes for tetrahedon
set uniforms for tetrahedon
draw tetrahedon

use program for sphere
set attributes for sphere
set uniforms for sphere
draw sphere
```

- use program = `gl.useProgram`
- set attributes = `gl.enableVertexAttribArray`, `gl.vertexAttribPointer`
- set uniforms = `gl.uniformXXX`, `gl.activeTexture` + `gl.bindTexture`

[See this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049058/using-a-different-vertex-and-fragment-shader-for-each-object-in-webgl)

Comment: Thank you for clearning up the confusion for me. Your notes have helped me in gaining a better understanding the basics of WebGL. Just one further question relating to this project: I previously managed to get the cube shape to rotate. I now have all the objects in the canvas, but I can't get the cube to rotate again. Debugging the code gives me "this uniform location doesn't correspond to the current program" - referring to the gl.uniform information in render(). I updated the code structure on the gist page to reflect the current state of the code. Thank you.

Comment: So a few things. #1, uniform locations are specific to each GLSL program. If you have 2 programs both with "theta" their location is specific to that program. Everytime you call `gl.linkProgram` that's a different program even if it uses the same shaders. #2 the functions `gl.createXXX`, `gl.bufferData`, `gl.texImage2D`, `gl.compileShader`, `gl.linkShader` are *generally* functions that should be called at initialization time only. There are cases where they might be called during rendering but I'm guessing not in your case..

Comment: Im trying to draw multiple objects also, but I'm a bit confused, I understand there are a limited amount of bufers to bind the data to (ARRAY_BUFFER being only one) but what if I want to draw huundreds of "buffered" geometries, each one with its own unique set of vertices etc, how would I go about doing it? Is it bad to call gl.bindBuffer in the loop? If so do I need to make a separate program for each new geometry (if I run out of other buffers in the current program), and simply call "useProgram" in the loop, as suggested in your link? Is that the best way to go about it?